# Run an install program remotely

Tags: vb.net

I need to be able to run an installer program in different machines, this is basically to minimized users inputs, for example, I have 7 different computer connected thru a private network, but machine 1 is the one that resides main database and other softwares, I need to run from machine 1 a software update to all machines independently.

```
Dim p As New Process
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "\\SHOP" & box & TextBox1.Text & "\E\VastUpdate\AutoITUpdater.exe"
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i AutoITUpdater.exe"
    p.Start()
```

Comment: removed 'please help.'

Answer (score 1):

Use [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

Here is an example code:

```
Dim application As String = "\\SHOP" & box & TextBox1.Text & "\E\VastUpdate\AutoITUpdater.exe"
Dim arguments As String = "/i AutoITUpdater.exe"
Dim location_of_psexec As String = "c:\pstools\psexec.exe"
Dim remote_machine As String = "remote_machine"

Dim process As Process = New Process()
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
process.StartInfo.FileName = location_of_psexec
process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("\\{0} -c ""{1}"" ""{2}""", remote_machine, application, arguments)

process.Start()
```

I am assuming in my code that the application path (e.g. `"\\SHOP" & box & TextBox1.Text & "\E\VastUpdate\AutoITUpdater.exe"`) is relative to your machine, not the remote machine.

If you want to use a path relative to the remote machine, simply remove the `-c` from the value of `process.StartInfo.Arguments`